# Как сделать, чтобы знак в else WriteLn('<'); не выскакивал постоянно?

Tags: delphi

```
var

a,b : integer;
begin
ReadLn(a,b);
if a = b
        then WriteLn('=');
if a >= b then WriteLn('>')

        else WriteLn('<');

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, сам уже разобрался:

```
var 
  a,b: integer;    
begin
  ReadLn(a,b);
  if a = b then
    WriteLn('=')
  else
    if a >= b then
      WriteLn('>')
    else
      WriteLn('<');
end.
```

Comment: @Joks, не по теме, но почитайте, как правильно форматировать код: http://vk.cc/3tlkey , а во-вторых, не стоит так опрометчиво задавать вопросы, а посидеть и подумать, что делает ваша программа. Программа выполняет только то, что от неё требуют. Успехов!

    begin
       ReadLn(a,b);
       if a = b then 
           WriteLn('=')
       else
          if a >= b then WriteLn('>')
          else WriteLn('<');
    end.

Comment: >= там совсем ни к чему, = уже к тому моменту отсеено

Answer (score 2):

Ещё, прикола ради - можно вообще без вложенных if/else: :))

```
uses 
  Math;
var  M : array [-1..1] of Char = '<=>';
  a, b : integer;
begin
  ReadLn(a, b);
  WriteLn(a,' ',M[Sign(a-b)],' ',b);
  ReadLn    
end.
```

Или даже так:

```
uses
  Math;
var
  a, b : integer;
     M : array [-1..1] of String = ('less than', 'equal to', 'greater than');
begin
  ReadLn(a, b);
  WriteLn(a,' ',M[Sign(a-b)],' ',b);
  ReadLn
end.
```

Comment: @Barklay, а delphi целое переполнение отлавливает?

А то ведь (для 32 разрядных int) 

    a: -2000000000  b: 2000000000  a - b: 294967296

(да, sign + !!!).

--

Впрочем, это давно известный  факт, что `a - b` для выяснения знака можно использовать, только для ограниченного диапазона данных.

Comment: Ну если бы Вы использовали такие большие числа, то, наверное, самым лучшим (т.е. коротким) решением было бы изменение в программе типа числа: a, b : int64;
У Sign() есть перегруженный метод, который работает и с этим диапазоном, таким образом изменение всего одного идентификатора в программе решило бы проблему, впрочем этого же можно было бы добиться и не меняя тип чисел {a,b}, оставив его прежним, но тогда лишь только сделать приведение типа в вызове ф-ции: M[Sign(int64(a)-b)], что автоматически привело бы к вызову перегруженной фунции, работающей с int64. Т.о. проблема была бы решена!

Comment: uses
  Math;
var  M : array [-1..1] of String = ('less than', 'equal to', 'greater than');
  a, b : integer; //int64;
begin
  a := -2000000000; b := 2000000000;
  WriteLn(a, ' ', M[Sign(int64(a)-b)], ' ', b);
  ReadLn
end.

Comment: @Barklay, это верно. Главное в принципе не забывать о проблеме переполнения.

Comment: @avp - Согласен! 
Да, а что касается того, что отлавливает ли Delphi переполнение или нет, то ответ утвердительный - да, конечно же отлавливает! Два различных решения при таком переполнении я уже привел выше.

Comment: @Barklay, не понял, что Вы имеете в виду под термином "именное обращение".

Если ссылку на ник, то у Вас получилось (@avp -- собака  + ник). 

Если сообщение "в личку" -- это здесь не предусмотрено.

Вообще, основные правила [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/faq/), а краткая инструкция по форматированию -- [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/markdown_help/)

Comment: @avp Спасибо! - С этим уже разобрался! За ссылки - особо!

Comment: Отлично.

Что же касается *отлавливания переполнения*, то я имел в виду вброс исключения (или какой-то аналогичный механизм, скажем, сигналы в \*nix), а не переход к повышенной разрядности (согласитесь, для int64 проблема-то на самом деле не исчезает, просто уходит из практической плоскости).

И тут в принципе я набрел на [ссылку](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsoverflowchecking_xml.html) о видимо обычно отключенном флаге  OVERFLOWCHECKS  компилятора.

Возможно кому-то это окажется полезным.